# React - pass a variable to css sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I would like to understand how to pass a value from a React component to the css stylesheet.

Basically I have a

```
.container {
   height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
   background-image:url(...)
   }

.container h1{
display:flex;
justify-content:center
transform:translateY(calc(-47%+0px)
letter-spacing:0px
}
```

When the user is scrolling down (or up), I would change the 0px to a value obtained on my React component (**currentScrollY**) beside to increase (or decrease - the boolean **goingUp**) the letter spacing and the translation on Y's axis.

```
const prevScrollY = useRef(0);
const [goingUp, setGoingUp] = useState(false);

const onScroll = (e) => {
const currentScrollY = e.target.scrollTop;
if (prevScrollY.current < currentScrollY && goingUp) {
  setGoingUp(false);
}
if (prevScrollY.current > currentScrollY && !goingUp) {
  setGoingUp(true);
}
prevScrollY.current = currentScrollY;
console.log(goingUp, currentScrollY);
};
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't "pass a value to a stylesheet", you use a dynamic style for the component.  Like this: `<div style={{ letterSpacing: goingUp ? 10 : 5 }}>` https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: you may need something like css-in-js, you can try explore styled-component https://styled-components.com/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG :) A last question, why is not working style={{ letterSpacing: goingUp ? 10 : `${currentScrollY}px` }}.  I get a error currentScrollY is not defined

Comment: That variable only exists inside your `onScroll` function; if you want to use it in your JSX you have to make it available there (for instance by using a state variable instead).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG, is not clear for me why goingUp is available and currentScrollY is not, ill try to study more and figure out more for state variables to make it available, thank you for your advice :)

Comment: THANKS @ChrisG, finally I created a useState `const [currentScrollY, setCurrentScrollY] = useState(0)`, then amended the `setCurrentScrollY(currentScrollY)` that made available the currentScrollY to the css. I have very few points to value any answer but as soon will get more points I will remember your help :)